# Android - Get EditText and show dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I want my application can get user's input of time (HH:mm) from EditText widget.
Based on this time value my app needs to show a dialog when current time matches entered time.

Gaauwe

****Edit****

I want to place an EditText widget in my app. 
A user will fill it with some time value (e.g. 10:30).
Then when real time (10:30) come up a dialog will be shown.

Comment: can u plz explain in detail, exactly what u want to do?

Comment: Do you mean, you want the time when user typed that particular text?

Comment: yes i want to get the time the user typed and show a dialog at that time, every day.

Comment: the time formate same for time when use enter time?

Comment: yes, i want to get exactly what the user type.

Comment: it would appear that he needs to know how to set up a background scheduler.

Comment: @mikebabcock i think so. But i know how to show a dialog, but i need to know how i can show it on the time the user typed.

Comment: ok obviously, you are new to the whole thing, but what you are trying to do might require a bit of a research on your side for the AlarmManager. That said, have a look at this simple tutorial ( and copy/paste the code if you must). http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html  It looks really simple and I think it can help you learn.

Comment: @Zortkun but as i read alarm manager, you have 10 seconds and then the alarm shows. I want to show a dialog when its for example 10:30 not 10:30 seconds later. Do you understand me?

Comment: @Gaauwe :) perfect, young padawan. now replace that line "calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);" with you custom value that you will get from the user and covert to decimal..etc

Comment: @Zortkun Sorry for being a noob ): but how can i convert the time a user typed in the edittext to seconds to go? Do you understand me?

Comment: @Gaauwe hehe donT worry.. but i ll urge you to google for "parse int from String android" and figure out urself... another hint: use **MINUTE** precision instead of **SECONDS** in `calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, !!!your input in integers here!!!);`

Comment: Honestly to help you here somebody needs to give you just working example of what you need. I doubt that many people who know how to do it have lots of spare time. You need to do some R/D to understand basics and after ask concrete questions if you didn`t get how to do something. You got a good starting point - AlarmManager. Update your  question while going. This is the way how it works, good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for this.

I d suggest you have a look at some tutorials like these to help you get started

http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/android/android-creating-alarm-alarmmanager

http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/alarm-notification

Answer (score 1):

try this :
use the service : then when user enter time starts a service when system time and user entered time match the shows..

Answer (score 1):

That is not too difficult. When user finished editing you EditText, read the time value and create instance of AlarmManager with start time calculated as difference between current time and whatever user wrote in the EditText. Better to use TimePicker to avoid parsing user`s input. Add receiver for you AlarmManager, receiver will start Service which will show dialog or do anything you want. You need to use AlarmManager because if your device is sleeping nothing will wake it up except system call like AlarmManager. @Zortkun 's post with links will help you to figure out how manage AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the data out of the EditText with:

```
findViewById(R.id.yourEditText).getText().toString();
```

The rest of your question I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

RAW WAY!

So when user put text inside edittext and click button, you could save text in this way:

```
String time = findViewById(R.id.yourEditText).getText().toString();
```

and start a thread that check for time, and when time is equal to user's string time, you can show a dialog :)

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      while(new Date().getLocalTime()!=usersTime){ // is just pseudocode
          Dialog.show();
      }   
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes i know how to get text from edittext, but i need to know how i can launch a dialog on the time the user typed. Can you maybe help me with that?

Comment: The method getLocalTime() is undefined for the type Date

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable userTime inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: Thread will not work when device will go in a sleep mode. Only if it is background running service, in this way it will be killing battery.

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method show() from the type Dialog

Comment: try new Date().toString() -> Converts this Date object to a String of the form: dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy. and you can check only the middle value. try to create a method to do this

Comment: why static? is your class static? if yes you have to instantiate your dialog in a static way like a global variable

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to understand...

Seeing as you know how to pull the text from an EditText, you'll need an if statement.

Something that compares that time to the current time.

```
        if (editTime == realTime) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RING RING RING",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Use something like this:

[Read this to figure out how to get a string of current time.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html)